# Python, Rodeo gives "Unable to execute" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, rodeo

I have python 3.5 installed on my Windows 10 system. I am using Rodeo 2.5.2 as the interpreter. I had written a python code >800-900 lines on the same. When I try to select it all and trigger it, it just says "Unable to Execute" and shows nothing else whereas when I try to select ~100-200 lines and then run it chunk by chunk it works fine. I am not able to understand why this is happening & how to solve this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some functions which are not being used in the main function.

I had a similar issue and it was resolved as soon as I erased all the functions which were useless and didn't appear in my main function

Good Luck